# Why $P\{S_n\in A\}\leq P\{S_n\neq S_n'\}+P\{S_n'\in A\}$?

Tags: probability

Let $S_n$ and $S_n'$ two r.v. Why 
$$P\{|S_n|>\varepsilon\}\leq P\{S_n\neq S_n'\}+P\{|S_n'|>\varepsilon\}\ \ ?$$

Is it true in general that $$P\{S_n\in A\}\leq P\{S_n\neq S_n'\}+P\{S_n'\in A\}\ \ ?$$

To me, $P\{S_n\in A\}=P\{S_n'\in A\mid S_n=S_n'\}+P\{S_n\in A\mid S_n\neq S_n'\}$, but it looks strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
P(S \in A) &= P(S \in A, S = S') + P(S \in A, S \ne S')\\
&= P(S' \in A, S = S') + P(S \in A, S \ne S')\\
&\le P(S' \in A) + P(S \ne S')
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Why this last inequality ? I don't understand it. Thank you

Comment: This is just the monotonicity of measures, i.e. if $M \subset N$ then $P(M) \le P(N)$.

Answer (score 0):

You claim $P(A) = P(A|B) + P(A|B^c)$ but this is wrong.

It holds $P(A) = P(A|B)\cdot P(B) + P(A|B^c)\cdot P(B^c)$ instead